# Installed lubuntu on eeepc 1025c - now won't boot

Tags: multi-boot, lubuntu, eee-pc

I purchased an [Asus EeePc 1025c](http://uk.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1025C/). Dissapointed with its windows performance, I decided to install Ubuntu + LXDE, that is Lubuntu (lightweight, and 1025c only has 1GB RAM).

The installation went fine, until I decided to close the lid of the pc to carry it to somewhere else. That is to say, I think I made the computer hiberante\suspend\sleep.
I did so from Lubuntu, and now PC doesn't boot, no POST, no nothing.
Just: Wireless LED on, some lamp-image LED on, Battery LED flashing (charging-status), PC-On-LED on and that's it.
I hear fans, not sure about the HD.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the "Instant On, Always on Standby" Feature this computer has.
I know it even has a whole /dev/sda4 partition of 16MB probably dedicated to that.

At first it went on for 2 seconds and turned itself off, and after I dissassembled the entire computer, took the RAM out (read a tip somewhere) and reassembled it, it goes ON, and the screen remains As-Is, black.

How should I go about fixing my unfortunate case?

Comment: could be a hardware failure (propbably completely disassembling the computer, as it is needed to access the ram, dind't help about it), does it boot with a live ubuntu 12.04 (any variant will do the same) on a usb key?

Comment: If you don't even see the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test), I doubt it has anything to do with installing Ubuntu.

Comment: yes, of course if it doesn't bring up POST it fails way before Ubuntu can do any damage... and by disassembling it the author also has lost the warranty.

Comment: Try connecting an external monitor to it, you might be lucky and it is only the laptop's screen that is screwed. Does it beep at you? Do the fans spin? Can you hear the hard drives spinning?

Comment: No Post, Figured it's something with the "Instant On, Always On Standby". I hear something, probably fans, no beep, I'm not sure about the hard drive. (By installing "Third-Party OS" or something like that, I already did void the warranty). Might be an Asus Instant On specific tip to redo this.

Comment: maybe while installing ubuntu you changed the partition table and instant on doesn't find things where it expects them to be... if it's this, it kinda sucks...

Comment: Maybe it's possible to get the information for the fourth partition online, takout the HDD and reinstall everything the way instant on expects it?